# Dynamically inserting elements in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have three tabs(Article(s), Visitor(s), Subscription(s)) and a common place of pagination; where each tab data will be provided with pagination. On click of the respective tab; respective ng-view are coming to picture and controllers are responding properly. For this custom made pagination; i want to update the number if `<li>`  accordingly on the basis of the server response(number of pages available for next pagination).

```
<div ng-app="myLibrary">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/articleManager">Article(s)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/visitorManager">Visitor(s)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/subscriptionsManager">Subscription(s)</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul> //will behave as pagination toolbar and each <li> represents a page; after a minimum of 5 pages; i will add a combo(as in plan) to cater more page(s)
                <li ng-repeat="tPageObj in recordPageNumbers">
                    <span ng-click="fetchPage(tPageObj.pageIndex)">{{ tPageObj.pageIndex }}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

When the view is rendered(after getting the data from server; i have a array with the $scope ($scope.recordPageNumbers) and calculating the page(s) accordingly. Even in the console; it shows appropriate number of page(s); but i am unable to figure-out  why the ng-repeat is not behaving(as i learned so-far; being two way binding modification in the model will trigar the view update) as it should.

```
var myLibrary = angular.module('myLibrary', ['ngRoute', 'ngTable']);

    myLibrary.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {  
        $routeProvider.when('/', 
            { templateUrl : 'angular-view/article.html', controller : 'articleList' } );
        $routeProvider.when('/articleManager', 
            { templateUrl : 'angular-view/article.html', controller : 'articleList' } );
        $routeProvider.when('/visitorManager', 
            { templateUrl : 'angular-view/visitor.html', controller : 'visitorList' } );
        $routeProvider.when('/subscriptionsManager', 
            { templateUrl : 'angular-view/subscriptions.html', controller : 'subscriptions' } );  
    }]);

    myLibrary.controller('articleList', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.articleListArray = [];
        $scope.recordPageNumbers = [];
        $http.get('ngMyLibrary.do?action=ALLARTICLE')
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.articleListArray = response.data; //sending data to `ng-view`
                var totalPageCount = response.totalPageCount;//calculating pages and according creating the `recordPageNumbers` array.
                if(totalPageCount){
                    for(var counter = 1; counter <= totalPageCount; counter++)
                        $scope.recordPageNumbers.push({pageIndex : counter, disableButton : false});
                } else {
                    $scope.recordPageNumbers.push({pageIndex : 1, disableButton : true});
                }
                console.log($scope.recordPageNumbers); //console show as expected
            }
        );
    });
```

**Console:**

```
[Object { pageIndex=1}, Object { pageIndex=2}, Object { pageIndex=3}, Object { pageIndex=4}, Object { pageIndex=5}, Object { pageIndex=6}]
```

I tried with `{{ $index }}` as the loop index of the `ng-repeat` but it din't work as well. Please help. I am newbie to `ng`; hence could not figure out the way to check within the `ng-repat` tag through debug.

Comment: Friends; i tried to attach screen-shot of the UI to give you proper picture; but failed as i don't have sufficient reputation. Thanks!!

Comment: What does `not behaving` mean? Not clear what the exact problem is you are having

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="tPageObj in recordPageNumbers">` supposed to create `<span>` but not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full project structure it is a bit difficult to know.  But have you checked to see if the controllers scope covers the HTML you are trying to use?

For example update the first line to be

```
<div ng-app="myLibrary" ng-controller="articleList">
```

It could be that the way you have it set up with the routing, the controller is only being responsible for the HTML being injected into the ng-view part of the page.

Comment: In the view; data are coming perfectly; that means controller is rightly injecting the data to right view(as defined in route). Already tried(explicitly specifying controller); but no success. Even i tried putting `<button>` instead of `<li>` but still no result.

Comment: Secondly; i tried to put the screen-shot; but due to lack of reputation i am unable to do so.

Comment: And lastly; i had put the array into the `$scope` itself. Hence it needs to be available to my page(`jsp` where i am creating the `<li>`). Am i right on this please??